# Python RegEx Discrepancy vs Kodos and RegExr: Can't Filter Specific Character in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python 2.6.3. When I do:

```
import re, urllib
f = urllib.urlopen(website)
z = f.read()
a = re.findall(r'(\b\d*\SLegos\b)[^\\/bLegos\b]', z)
print a
```

I get:

```
['/Legos', '/Legos', '525Legos', '53Legos', '11Legos', '8Legos', '10Legos', '2Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '9Legos', '1Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '/Legos']
```

If I put the website as source code into either Kodos or RegExr by gSkinner and use my above RegEx code they both say I should get:

```
'525Legos', '53Legos', '11Legos', '8Legos', '10Legos', '2Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '9Legos', '1Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos', '0Legos'
```

Which is much closer to the data I want.

How do I drop the `'/Legos'` from returning in my Python regex?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: how about showing some sample of the html you want to match?

Answer (score 3):

your regex is too complicated and erroneous, you could just use:

```
\b(\d+Legos)\b
```

if you don't really need `Legos` in your output, you could of course simply move it out of the brackets:

```
\b(\d+)Legos\b
```